# Refactoring org files (moving data without breaking links)?

Tags: emacs, hyperlink, refactoring, org-mode, break

I'm looking for some sort of a workflow that will let me move things around freely without breaking links.

Since I almost always use `org-store-link` or `org-capture` to link to anything, I'm considering a workflow like this:

1. Any time `org-store-link` or `org-capture` is called from an org file, insert a copy of the exact link being stored/captured into the current heading's properties. Of course, I might just have a wrapper function that does the insert and then calls the respective `org` function
2. On every save, search the current file for any such identifiers that do not match their exact current location. File moves will break links, too, so the script might should run periodically on all org files - maybe on emacs start-up.
3. If any non-matches are found, then search for backlinks that point to the old identifiers, update those backlinks with the new location, and then update the identifier itself to the new location.

A helper function that finds all headings with org-links to them, but without an identifier, would help me get my current org files ready for the system.

Before I get started, does this sound like a good idea, how might it be improved, and has somebody else already done it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org-mode` has an option to assign a unique id to each entry and use that in the links.  This lets links keep working even when the target is moved.  Set the variable `org-id-link-to-org-use-id` to `t` and the id will be created and stored in the `ID` property.  `org-insert-link` will insert links of the for `id:<id>`.

Comment: Thank you.  This will get me most of the way to what I'm after.  `org-id-get-create` will help, too.

Comment: I've discovered something odd.  After calling `org-id-get-create` once, any time use `org-store-link` or `org-capture`, `org-id-get-create` is called automatically.  This is exactly the functionality I want, but I don't understand why I have to call it manually the first time.

Does anyone know?

Comment: This is because `org-id-link-to-org-use-id` is `nil` by default.  Once you activate ids in a buffer, it would not make sense to not rely on it.